# acer aspire x3995 desktop continuous beep on startup

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, post

PC was beeping 4 short beeps and after some google decided to move ram to a different slot. I didn't ground myself and now it continually beeps on startup.

I have unplugged everything from mobo excluding gfx, and what I assume is cpu (soldered in place on front of tower where usb slots are). And not taken fan off to get to heat sink fan.

Still continuous beep on startup . I assume its psu, or I fried mobo. But not really sure so any advice / help would be appreciated.

Acer aspiire x3995 i5 .

http://www.acer.com/ac/en/AE/content/model/DT.SJLEM.036

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: The CPU will most certainly not be soldered "on front of tower where usb slots are".  The CPU will be below the largest heatsink + fan in a socket on the motherboard.

Comment: Yea apologies for the layman sentence... Is it a necessary to take the fan off to check it is in place fine? Thanks for your reply

Comment: It's unlikely to be your CPU.  To check the CPU you would have to remove its fan and heatsink, but it's very unlikely and there's not much you can do to test it unless you have another CPU for the same socket lying around.  So I don't recommend touching it.

Answer (score 0):

Though it *could* be that ESD fried a component, it's much more likely the issue is due to the change in RAM position.

1. Check the connectors in the RAM slot for bent pins and the gold-plated connectors on the RAM for broken traces (can sometimes be fixed with *careful* soldering).
2. Replace the RAM in the original position.
3. Reseat it carefully: some connectors are tight. Check that the RAM latches are fully engaged.

Lest us know if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Would the beep still occur if no RAM is attached? I places one ram stick back in, but canr remember which slot the remainder goes in (3 left) . One was in far blue slot, then a black slot is free, blue slot, black alot. Assume it would be second blue one, but unsure if they should be side by side? Thanks for the response

Comment: It depends on the motherboard model.  Find the motherboard model and search online for its manual.

Comment: The mobo is an Acer dib75l- Lena. Cant find any manual yet / beep codes reference but will continue searching

Comment: Also, have done all ram positions, checking etc and still same issue